# Can we customize SwiftEventBus to notify only for the current active screen and not all the places where it is registered?

Tags: ios, swift

Can we customize [SwiftEventBus](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus)  Library to only trigger in the current active ViewController.

I'm trying to trigger an action when ever a notification occurs, so i'm using swift event bus to trigger when ever a push notification comes but it is triggering in all the places it is registered. Can we make so that it will only trigger the action in the active view. If not is there any other library I can use?

Comment: Hi you try my answer or not?

Comment: I have a navigation controller for all the viewcontrollers will it cause any issue while unregistering?

Comment: i think no, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be enough to deregister inactive ViewControllers as mentioned in the SwiftEventBus [readme](https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus#unregistering)?

```
//Perhaps on viewDidDisappear depending on your needs
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    SwiftEventBus.unregister(self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify library(or subclass SwiftEventBus) like below:

```
    @discardableResult
    open class func on(_ target: AnyObject, name: String, sender: Any? = nil, queue: OperationQueue?, handler: @escaping ((Notification?) -> Void)) -> NSObjectProtocol {
        let id = UInt(bitPattern: ObjectIdentifier(target))

//modification start
        let handlerIner:((Notification?) -> Void) =  { [weak target] n in
            if let vc = target as? UIViewController, vc.view?.window != nil {  
                handler(n)
            }
        }

        let observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: name), object: sender, queue: queue, using: handlerIner)
// modification end
        let namedObserver = NamedObserver(observer: observer, name: name)

        Static.queue.sync {
            if let namedObservers = Static.instance.cache[id] {
                Static.instance.cache[id] = namedObservers + [namedObserver]
            } else {
                Static.instance.cache[id] = [namedObserver]
            }
        }

        return observer
    }
```