# Access object (pointer) form ObjectIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to re-access object from it's `ObjectIdentifier`

ex:

```
let controller = UIViewController() //assume controller has strong ref so it's not going to deallocate instantly 
let id = ObjectIdentifier(controller)
```

so how to access controller with it's ObjectIdentifier

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For converting an instance pointer to a “raw pointer” and back, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310021/1187415.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid strong reference to target:
https://github.com/cesarferreira/SwiftEventBus/blob/master/SwiftEventBus/SwiftEventBus.swift#L60

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878505/6630644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i get it.

```
let controller = UIViewController()

let id = ObjectIdentifier(controller)
let bitptr = UInt(bitPattern: id)

let _viewController:UIViewController? = unsafeBitCast(bitptr, to: UIViewController.self)
```

Comment: Well, I had no idea that was possible! For what it's worth though, I wouldn't recommend using such a type-unsafe way of retrieving the original value.

Comment: Why go via ObjectIdentifier? If the intention is to (unsafely!!!) convert an instance pointer to an integer and back then `let id = unsafeBitCast(controller, to: Int.self)` and `let vc = unsafeBitCast(id, to: UIViewController.self)` would do the trick. But note that this bypasses the reference counting: If the view controller is deallocated in between then this will crash. With the `Unmanaged` api you can do such conversions *and* retain/release the reference count accordingly, see the link at my above comment.

Comment: Sometimes you're spelunking through someone else's code that uses `ObjectIdentifier` and you want to do this conversion in the debugger, in which case this is a useful technique. @SPatel, [you can and should mark this as the accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

`ObjectIdentifier` is declared in the open sourced Swift Standard Library, so we can look at a snippet of it's implementation from [GitHub](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ObjectIdentifier.swift) (I have stripped out non-essential code and comments):

```swift
@frozen
public struct ObjectIdentifier {

  internal let _value: Builtin.RawPointer

  public init(_ x: AnyObject) {
    self._value = Builtin.bridgeToRawPointer(x)
  }

  public init(_ x: Any.Type) {
    self._value = unsafeBitCast(x, to: Builtin.RawPointer.self)
  }
}
```

We see that the implementation's stored `_value` is marked `internal`, so you will not be able to access it from code defined in other modules at all. In addition, only a pointer to the object is stored, meaning there is no 'direct' access to the object anyway.

Your best option is to just keep around the object, and create an `ObjectIdentifier` as and when you need it. Alternatively, you can re-implement `ObjectIdentifier` in your own module to be able to access the underlying object/pointer.